# Setting Cursor property has no effect

Tags: c#, cursor

I have a class that I've derived from System.Windows.Forms.Panel, and my application has a main form with one of these panels. On the whole, the panel works great! The only thing I'm having trouble with is setting the cursor. Whether I'm setting it to one of the static members of the Cursors class (Default, WaitCursor, etc.) or setting it to a custom cursor that I've loaded from a resource, the end result is the same: it does nothing. I still see the default mouse pointer, no matter what. This line of code is inside a method of my panel-derived class:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

I can set a break point there, and see that this line is being hit when I expect it to. I've also created an override for the OnCursorChanged method, and set a breakpoint in there just to see if it's being triggered. I can verify that both breakpoints are being hit when I expect them to. However, the cursor just never changes. There must be something that I'm missing. Does anyone have any ideas?

P.S. I also did try setting Current.Cursor as well, however that did not help.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the static property of the cursor class instead of using `this.Cursor`:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

or check [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/18b8b65e-03cd-4a4f-9b7e-4e44ea5ac5df) for more information and workarounds on setting the cursor.