# Can't Switch From 'WaitCursor' in Form Property Menu Pulldown

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Working in Visual Studio 2010 Express (C#):

Once I've switched the cursor to 'WaitCursor' in the pulldown menu, I can't change it to anything else. It seems like a bug to me. Can anyone else reproduce this? I did run a debug once or twice before trying to change the cursor again. Or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cursor.Current vs. this.Cursor in .Net (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c)

Comment: Had the same issue in Visual Studio 2017, .net framework 4.7.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Had the same problem, solution was embarrassingly simple, yet infuriating. There's another property called UseWaitCursor. If this is set to true (as mine was, accidentally), you are unable to change the Cursor property to anything other than WaitCursor.

If someone can explain why there are two separate properties for setting the cursor, I'm sure we'd all love to hear it.

Comment: Form.Cursor applies only to the Form itself, and can be set to any of the enumerated cursors; but Form.UseWaitCursor sets the Form.Cursor to WaitCursor for the form AND all child controls

Comment: Thanks @Gullbyrd - how frustrating!

Comment: as far as the explanation to why two separate properties were created, it's still a mystery :)

Answer (score 3):

There is a usewait cursor property you need to set it to false in vs2010

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with the context menu on a datagridview. I was setting UseWaitCursor on the form to true and then to false after everything loaded. The context menu continued to show WaitCursor. I ended up setting the UseWaitCursor = false on the actual context menu after the load a