# Should Application.UseWaitCursor be used?

Tags: c#, .net, mouse-cursor

Are there any dangers in using `Application.UseWaitCursor` to turn off and on the hourglass mouse pointer?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c/302865#302865

Comment: What is your response to the concern raised in the comment below your answer to that question?

Comment: I don't see a concern, somebody just used the class from the wrong thread.  The more typical use of a wait cursor is when you *don't* use a thread.

Answer (score 6):

The "danger" is in not restoring the cursor.

You can do this with `try…finally` blocks to ensure that even if an exception is thrown you restore the cursor, or clean up the syntax a bit by wrapping this functionality in a class that implements `IDisposable` so that you can use `using` blocks instead.

```
  public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
  {
    public WaitCursor()
    {
      Application.UseWaitCursor = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
      Application.UseWaitCursor = false;
    }
  }
```

Usage:

```
  using (new WaitCursor())
  {

    // do stuff - busy, busy, busy

  } // here the cursor will be restored no matter what happened
```

Answer (score 3):

If the application will be locked until the long running operation is completed, it will be correct to use `Application.UseWaitCursor`. But if you have multiple forms where only one form will be locked, it is better to set the `Cursor` property explicit on the form.

You should also remeber to put `Application.UseWaitCursor = false;` in a `finally`block, so you ensure that the cursor is reset in cases where an application exception is thrown.

Comment: Setting the cursor on the form doesn't work, a textbox control overrides it for example.  This is really the reason the property exists in the first place.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but only for enabled controls. If you have a long running process which locks the form, you also need to disable the possibility to enter data. Eg. put all controls in a panel which you can disable (Enable = false;) during the processing.