# How to skip the dialog of printing in printDocument.print() and print page directly?

Tags: c#, .net, winapp

When I use `MyPrintDocument.print()` in a Windows application written in C#, a dialog is shown for the Windows processing print routine with a cancel button. I don't want this dialog shown, is it possible?

If not, which way should I use? My program uses a thermal printer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Which [PrintController](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printcontroller) are you using.

> The .NET Framework includes three print controllers that are derived from `PrintController` that help accomplish common tasks. The `StandardPrintController` prints a document to a printer. The `PreviewPrintController` generates a preview of what the document will look like when printed and is used by the `PrintPreviewControl` and `PrintPreviewDialog` classes. The `PrintControllerWithStatusDialog` provides a printing status dialog during the printing process.

It sounds like you are using the [`PrintControllerWithStatusDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.printcontrollerwithstatusdialog) `PrintController`.

---

*Caveat:* I am not in a position to verify that the basic `PrintController` doesn't act the same way.

According to this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/cb78e90b-bf27-462c-90d3-78d935f49ed1) the `PrintControllerWithStatusDialog` is the default:

He suggests something like this:

```
MyPrintDocument.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController();
```

Answer (score 5):

If you don't assign the `PrintDocument.PrintController` property then you get a default print controller.  An instance of `PrintControllerWithStatusDialog` which displays the progress dialog, counting pages and generally informing the user that the program is unresponsive for a reason but otherwise not hung.

Simply reassign it in the form constructor.  Boilerplate code is:

```vb
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        PrintDocument1.PrintController = New System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController
    End Sub
End Class
```

And you'll have to do something else to tell the user that a print is in progress.  At least display an [hourglass cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c/302865#302865).