# System.Drawing.Printing.PrintDocument without popup printing page 1 of document

Tags: vb.net, winforms, printdocument

we have a windows form application trying to do regular printouts.

Clients are complaining with popup coming up while we do multiple print outs saying printing page 1 of document. ( i guess im  not allowed to post pictures, i dont have the reputation, so here is the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYbvl.png))

Is there a way to hide these. or should  we be using a different method. Thank you.

```
Function Print()
    Dim prn As New Printing.PrintDocument
    Using (prn)
        prn.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = sPrnName
        prn.PrinterSettings.Copies = 1
        AddHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
        prn.Print()
        RemoveHandler prn.PrintPage, AddressOf Me.PrintPageHandler
    End Using


End Sub



Private Sub PrintPageHandler(ByVal sender As Object, _
   ByVal args As Printing.PrintPageEventArgs)
    Dim myFont As New Font("Courier New", 9)
    args.Graphics.DrawString(_sPrnRows, _
       New Font(myFont, FontStyle.Bold), _
       Brushes.Black, 5, 5)
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to prevent those dialogues being displayed but you can make them more meaningful by setting the `DocumentName` property of the `PrintDocument`.  It will then display your document name instead of just "document".

Comment: They are insistent on removing them or hiding them. There must be away to show them behind application screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572420/how-to-skip-the-dialog-of-printing-in-printdocument-print-and-print-page-direc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is from question albert found. 
prn.PrintController = new System.Drawing.Printing.StandardPrintController()