# C# printing rdlc report unattended

Tags: c#, printing, report, rdlc

I am working on a C# WinForm application that currently has several RDLC reports in it, and those reports need to print at a given time without any user interaction.

The good news, is I found code to do that at [Printing A Local Report Without Preview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252091.aspx)

Unfortunately, while that works fairly well, when it prints, it puts up a small window saying "Printing page x of y" - is there any way to hide/suppress that window, so it can print silently while the user continues to work within the application?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind - I found the solution on my own:

Turns out all you need to do is add the following line before doing the printDoc.Print in the code:

printDoc.PrintController = new StandardPrintController();

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using `PrintDocument` you can use this solution:

[How to skip the dialog of printing in printDocument.print() and print page directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572420/how-to-skip-the-dialog-of-printing-in-printdocument-print-and-print-page-direc)