# How salve PrintDocument without confirm dialog?

Tags: c#

NOTE: The other questions have not solved my problem.

I’ve got an PrintDocument object type and I would like to save its content in PDF format.
Within the object already exists the .print () method, however when running this method shows up a box asking where to save the file. Instead, I need to save the generate file in a specific directory, without the need for the user to choose the name and location for the file.

PS.
I tried to perform the procedure:[How to skip the dialog of printing in printDocument.print() and print page directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10572420/how-to-skip-the-dialog-of-printing-in-printdocument-print-and-print-page-direc)
But can not. We came to create a file in the folder set with that name set, however the file creates empty and still appears the dialog box.

Comment: I tried to perform the procedure:How to skip the dialog of printing in printDocument.print() and print page directly? But can not. We came to create a file in the folder set with that name set, however the file creates empty and still appears the dialog box.

Comment: Why can you not perform the proposed solution? Is your printer unplugged? Show us what you tried. Are you getting an error? Show it to us. We can't help you until you post code that displays the problem.