# Cursor.Wait after printDialog

Tags: vb.net, winforms, mouse-cursor

I'm having a little problem. I set the cursor to wait status. After calling the PrintDialog the cursor returns in default status. I can't set the cursor to wait status again. The code is like this:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
[...]
Dim result As DialogResult = printDialog.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    Return
End If
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
[...]
```

Comment: If the code reaches `Return` nothing else will be executes on that method. Maybe is that your problem?

Comment: No, I want the waitcursor only if `result` is not cancel. The `Return` is not reached in my tests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just did a small test with your code. When using your code my VS2012 didn't show up `Cursor.Current` but did not throw any exception when using it. So I changed it to

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor

Dim result As DialogResult = printDialog.ShowDialog()
If result = DialogResult.Cancel Then
    Return
End If
' not necesary any more
'Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
```

and the **WaitCursor stayed** after showing the printDialog.

**EDIT:** Found a pretty good explanation on **difference** between [Cursor.Current and Cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c)!

**EDIT2:** I changed my code to make use of HourGlass class from @HansPassant's example stated above. WaitCursor now stays even if you enter a textBox. Anyways - I was still able to get loss of the waitCursor when hovering over the border of eg. a textBox.

All in all IMO I think it's **not very good to force a waitCursor** when it is still possible to enter text aso. Perhaps you may *consider disabling controls* until some kind of actions has finished and afterwards change cursor back.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Hourglass.Enabled = True

    Dim result As DialogResult = PrintDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If result = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Return
    End If

    'Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
End Sub
```

**Hourglass.vb** - I hope I did not make any mistakes when converting it to vb.net

```
Public Class Hourglass
  Implements IDisposable

  Public Shared Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return Application.UseWaitCursor
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        If value = Application.UseWaitCursor Then Return
        Application.UseWaitCursor = value
        Dim f As Form = Form.ActiveForm
        If Not f Is Nothing AndAlso f.Handle <> IntPtr.Zero Then
            SendMessage(f.Handle, 32, f.Handle, 1)
        End If
    End Set
  End Property

  <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")>
  Private Shared Function SendMessage(hWnd As IntPtr, msg As IntPtr, wp As IntPtr, lp As IntPtr) As IntPtr
  End Function

  Public Sub Dispose() Implements IDisposable.Dispose
    Enabled = False
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Unfortunatly, the code you posted was my first choice, but in this case the cursor is not in wait status when over a text edit. Is there a solution?