# Change cursor using User32.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, cursor

I have a login form that disappears when logged in, a few moments later will the Main form be shown.

Now I want to show a **waitcursor**, when there is no form on screen.
I tried setting the cursor at the Login button click as follow:

```
this.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

And

```
this.Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
```

Both didn't work.

I Googled for this problem and the answers I get is: Use the **User32.dll** to set the Cursor. Okay fine, but I can't find any good documentation about how to change the cursor. Can someone give me an example, about how to change the cursor using the **User32.dll**?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cursor.Current vs. this.Cursor in .Net (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor-in-net-c)

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with Cursor and Cursor.Current, since that didn't work and I now want to use the User32.dll to solve my problem.

Comment: You didn't bother trying it or even reading it?  The answer uses your magic user32.dll incantation, it is at the bottom of the snippet.