# Cursor not updating with WaitCursor using TPL Task

Tags: c#, multithreading, cursor, task-parallel-library, task

I'm using a custom class (`WaitCursor`) to ensure that everytime I run a long running task, the `Cursor` is updated to show the `WaitCursor`. The original article and code can be found here [Implementing a WaitCursor Class](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/winforms/implementing-a-waitcursor-class). The `SendMessage()` and `GetForegroundWindow()` was taken from another answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302663/cursor-current-vs-this-cursor) at **StackOverflow**.

I was succesfully using this class when I used the `Thread` class to execute methods on separate threads. The cursor was updated during the execution and then reverted back to default.

Then I changed my logic to use the new `Task` class from **TPL Library** instead of `Thread` and now the cursor doesn't update anymore, I always see the default cursor.

No other changes where made in the code. Each call to the method of my class that create a new `Task`, is the same as before, when using `Thread`.

Here follows my code.

This is `TaskManager`, the class I use to manage execution of `Task`. ThreadManager was the previous class that shares exactly the same logic. The only difference is in the call to the method that create the new `Thread`/`Task`, so `Thread.Start()`/`Task.Factory.StartNew()`.

```
public class TaskManager
{
    private static readonly TaskManager Instance = new TaskManager();
    private readonly Dictionary<int, Task> _tasksList;
    private static int _tasksCount;

    private TaskManager()
    {
        _tasksList = new Dictionary<int, Task>();
        _tasksCount = 0;
    }

    public static TaskManager GetInstance()
    {
        return Instance;
    }

    public int StartNewTask(Action method)
    {
        try
        {
            Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(method);

            _tasksCount++;
            _tasksList.Add(task.Id, task);

            return task.Id;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Manage exception and log error
        }

        return -1;
    }
}
```

Call to create `Thread`/`Task`

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Before, using Thread class
    _threadManager.StartNewThread(MyMethod);

    // Now, using Task class
    _taskManager.StartNewTask(MyMethod);
}
```

`WaitCursor` class

```
public class WaitCursor : IDisposable
{
    public WaitCursor()
    {
        Enabled = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Enabled = false;
    }

    public static bool Enabled
    {
        get
        {
            return Application.UseWaitCursor;
        }

        set
        {
            if (value == Application.UseWaitCursor) return;
            Application.UseWaitCursor = value;
            Cursor.Current = value ? Cursors.WaitCursor : Cursors.Default;
            var handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            SendMessage(handle, 0x20, handle, (IntPtr)1); // Send WM_SETCURSOR
            Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position; // Trick to update the cursor even if the user doesn't move the mouse
        }
    }

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wp, IntPtr lp);

    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
}
```

`MyMethod` implementation

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    using (new WaitCursor())
    {
        // Do something that takes long time...
    }
}
```

The only thing I changed is `Task` instead of `Thread` and it's transparent to my method and to the `EventHandler` too.

What's the difference in managing cursor's updates between `Thread` and TPL `Task`?

**UPDATE 1**

As @JimMischel suggested, I tried to use the `Invoke` method instead of the `UseWaitCursor` class, but it doesn't work. This is the code.

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Start a new Task for MyMethod
    _taskManager.StartNewTask(MyMethod);
}

private void MyMethod()
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) DisableForm);
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) ToggleWaitCursor);

    // Do something that takes long time...

    Invoke((MethodInvoker) EnableForm);
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) ToggleWaitCursor);
}

private void ToggleWaitCursor()
{
    if (this.UseWaitCursor)
        this.UseWaitCursor = false;
    else
        this.UseWaitCursor = true;
}

private void DisableForm()
{
    this.Enabled = false;
}

private void EnableForm()
{
    this.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: You need to *show us the code* if you want us to have any idea what's wrong with it.  You only showed the code that calls the code that does this.

Comment: I updated the code and added the class I use to manage `Task`/`Thread`.

Comment: Seems like the line `Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position` is somewhat dangerous to be executing in a non-UI thread. I'm surprised that it doesn't throw an exception. One difference is that `Thread` by default creates a foreground thread. A `Task` is executed on a pool thread, which is a background thread. I wouldn't really expect that to matter here, though. Come to think of it, couldn't you just do an `Invoke` to set the cursor, and get rid of the complicated `WaitCursor` logic?

Comment: Proper attribution when you copy somebody's code is required at SO.

Comment: @HansPassant Yes, you're right! I forgot it! That was the article: [Implementing a WaitCursor Class](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/winforms/implementing-a-waitcursor-class). I also added it on the original question.

Comment: @JimMischel First I tried with a simpler approach, such as `Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor` etc... and then also with `Application.DoEvents()` but it was not working. Then I found this class that was working very good and I think it is also readable code and easy to use. I can try to remove the `Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position`, but as you already said, I don't think that would solve the problem. Anyway, that was a trick to force cursor update even when the user doesn't move the mouse. But, my real question is why that code works great with `Thread` but not with `Task`?

Comment: @JimMischel Removing `Cursor.Position = Cursor.Position` leads to a different behaviour! The cursor updates... but, when I move the mouse it reverts back to the arrow!

Comment: I realize the removing the code would cause different behavior. I'm just surprised it works. That notwithstanding, I'm still trying to understand why you don't just call [Form.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyzhdc6b(v=vs.110).aspx) to set the cursor rather than jumping through all the hoops required by that `WaitCursor` code. Seems like if you Invoked a call to set `Application.WaitCursor`, that would be executed on the UI thread, which *should* cause the UI to update. As to why your code works as a thread but not a task: no clue.

Comment: Because I'd like to separate Task calculation and UI update. So the `using (new WaitCursor()){...}` can do the trick. Did you read the article [here](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/winforms/implementing-a-waitcursor-class)? There's a complete explanation of possible problems that this class can handle in a simpler way. The other possibility is to insert everything inside a `try-catch-finally` block where inside the `try` block the cursor is set and then in case of exceptions, the cursor is resotred inside the `finally` block. But this code needs to be replicated for each method I call.

Comment: I read the article. And it's a useful thing if you want to do long calculations on the UI thread, as he demonstrates. But the article is fatally flawed specifically because he's performing long-running calculations on the UI thread. You, on the other hand, are doing the work in a background thread. So you shouldn't have the same problem. You could set `UseWaitCursor` before spawning the task. Or you could have the task invoke (or `BeginInvoke`) that setting. But if you want to overcomplicate your code with unnecessary goofiness, go for it.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work. Take a look at the updated question...

Comment: That's pretty odd. Does the updated version (using Invoke) work when you run it as a thread instead of as a task?

Comment: Yes, just tried but not working too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the problem was due to the `DisableForm` method. Somehow disabling the Form **stops the cursor updating process**.

So I finally found a solution by **replacing** the `DisableForm` method with `DisableControls`.

```
private void DisableControls()
{
    foreach (Control control in Controls)
    {
        control.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

The rest of the code, so the `WaitCursor` class and the usage of the class, remains the same:

```
using (new WaitCursor())
{
    // Do something that takes long time...
}
```